# what is the proper way to publish a React component module in NPM without external dependencies inside?

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, components

I'm trying to publish in NPM a component library made with React.

I don't want that it have external dependencies, even React modules, to have smallest possible file size and because the user will add this dependencies in the app.

I'm using `npm` and `webpack` to manage the dependencies.

- This is my `package.json` dependencies:

  ```
  "devDependencies": {
      "webpack": "^1.13.1",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
      "webpack-merge": "^0.13.0",
      "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
      "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
      "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
      "react": "^15.0.2",
      "react-dom": "^15.0.2"
    },
   "peerDependencies": {
     "react": "^15.0.2",
     "react-dom": "^15.0.2"
   }
  ```
- In my `webpack.config.js` file I have entry point as 'component.jsx' and output as 'lib.js' file

  ```
  // Source code entry
  entry: {
    lib: './src/components/component.jsx'
  },

  // Code Output 
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'lib.js'
  },
  ```
- I also included the "externals" attribute with the react modules to avoid webpack including it in the 'lib.js' output.

  ```
  externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom' : 'ReactDOM'
  }
  ```
- Finally this is the simple React component that i want to publish:

  ```
  import React from 'react';

  export default class Component extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <h1>MY COMPONENT</h1>
      );
    }
  }
  ```

I published it to NPM and installed it in another project. When I tried to use it after import React statement, it gives me an error saying that React is not defined (bundle.js:28448 Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined)

- My code to probe the component:

  ```
  import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  import Component from 'component';
  import $ from 'jquery';

  ReactDOM.render(
     <Component />,
     $("#app")
  );
  ```

Am I missing anything in the dependencies config?

Thanks

Comment: what version of npm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webpack `externals` defaults to your `libraryTarget`. Meaning that if you don't specify anything, it will output the external as `var`, and exepcts it to be a global variable.

*Webpack output using global:*

```
/* 76 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    module.exports = react;

/***/ },
```

You need to tell it to look for the dependency in the installed modules (to `require` it). in order to do that, change your externals to:

**Required change (in webpack.config):**

```
externals: {
  'react': 'commonjs react',
  'react-dom' : 'commonjs react-dom'
}
```

And then it will output it using commonjs.

*Webpack output using commonjs:*

```
/* 76 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    module.exports = require('react');

/***/ },
```

Reference to [webpack docs here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals).

Notice that I changed your externals back to lower case, since the value should be the dependency name to look for (in that case, `react` and `react-dom`).

(By the way, if you don't want to bundle any node_module, I recommend using [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals))

Comment: I have made the changes that you said me but I get an error at:  module.exports = require('react');  saying 
lib.js:8166 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Yes, I have change externals options adding the commonjs prefix

Comment: I have not defined the "library" and "libraryTarget" in the "ouput" config, could be this the problem?

Comment: When are you getting this error? can you try and add "libraryTarget":"umd" to the output config?

Comment: I get the error when I load the "lib.js" file, at the end it have a /***/ function(module, exports) {

 module.exports = require("React");

/***/ } that generate the error

Comment: you can't load it directly in the browser, you should import it from another project (like you intended)

Comment: Finally I've gotten it to work following this post   http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/javascript-library-starter-using-webpack-es6 . Basically itś like your suggestions, I don't know what was doing wrong. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you think my answer helped you in this case?

Comment: Sure, Can I mark it someway as resolved or give you some automatic feedback ?? I haveńt too much experience here in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You are making output file as `lib.js` but while rendering you are reading `bundle.js`. Please rename either output file as `bundle.js` or include `lib.js` in your `index.html` in place of including `bundle.js`.

Comment: Sorry, I dont explain it well, bundle.js is the compiled file of the app that consume the component module, and it haveńt the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a full Medium story because I had the same issue as you and there is no information about it.
Check it out: https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/how-to-create-a-react-component-and-publish-it-in-npm-668ad7d363ce

The main fix is to add the external `'react': 'commonjs react'` in the webpack.config.js file

Answer (score 0):

I searched for several days to find the best solution. In my opinion, [microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle) accomplishes this very easily. My build command is as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "microbundle build --globals react=React,react-dom=ReactDOM --jsx cloneElement,createContext,isValidElement,useContext,useReducer --jsxFragment Fragment --jsxImportSource react",
    "dev": "microbundle watch"
  },
```